Verilog code getting X for the signals in the simulation
I am new to verilog and I have two Verilog modules and a main.v module that is a topmodule and I want to simulate it with vivado xilinx. This is my main module. When I try to simulate it, I get X value for the signals. And I don't know if the problem is with the port declaration?
module main(
 
    clk2,
    inputsample0,
    inputsample1,
    outvec,
    rst
    );
    
    
parameter  N = 10;
parameter L =10;
integer M;
integer d;
reg [N-1 : 0] vector_class [9 : 0];
input  clk2;
input rst;
output reg outvec;
input inputsample0  ;
input inputsample1 ;
reg [N-1 : 0] feat_value [19:0];
reg [N-1 : 0] ch [19:0];
reg [N-1 : 0] feat [3:0];
reg [N-1 : 0] t1;
reg [N-1 : 0] t2;
reg [N-1 : 0] t3;
reg [N-1 : 0] distance [9:0];
reg [9:0] sum_dis;
wire  [N-1 : 0] inter_port;
reg [4:0] minVal;

assign clk2 = 1;


parameter threshold_value = 50;
reg [31:0] rng_seed;
integer rand_normal;
integer i;
integer a;
integer c;
integer rel_dist;
integer j;
integer f;
integer min_dist;    
assign inputsample0 = 4'b0101; // Assigning decimal value 5 to inputsample
// Wait for 10 time units
assign inputsample1 = 4'b0110; // Assigning decimal value 6 to inputsample



Asocciate_mem2 asocciate_mem2_inst (
    .outvec(inter_port),
    .clk(clk2),
    .rst(rst)
);


hamming hamming_inst (
    .input_vector(inter_port), // Connect the wire to the textVector input
    .clk(clk2)
);   
endmodule

These are my two other modules:
module Asocciate_mem2(
    outvec,
    inputsample,
    clk,
    rst
    );
    
parameter  N = 10;
parameter L =10;
integer M;
integer d;

input clk;
input rst;
input [3 : 0]inputsample  ;
reg [N-1 : 0] feat_value [19:0];
reg [N-1 : 0] ch [19:0];
reg [N-1 : 0] feat [1:0];
reg [N-1 : 0] t1;
reg [N-1 : 0] t2;
reg [N-1 : 0] t3;
reg [N-1 : 0] distance [9:0];
reg [9:0] sum_dis;

reg [4:0] minVal;
reg [N-1 : 0] textVector;
output [N-1 : 0] outvec;


parameter threshold_value = 50;
reg [31:0] rng_seed;
integer rand_normal;
integer i;
integer a;
integer c;
integer rel_dist;
integer j;
integer f;

integer min_dist;
    // Random number generator for Verilog 'normal' distribution (mean=0, std_dev=1)
    task rand_n;
        begin
        // Initialize random number
            
        // Generate a single random bit using XOR shift algorithm
            for (i = 0; i < 1; i = i + 1) begin
            // XOR shift algorithm for generating random numbers
                rng_seed = rng_seed ^ (rng_seed << 13);
                rng_seed = rng_seed ^ (rng_seed >> 17);
                rng_seed = rng_seed ^ (rng_seed << 5);
            // Assign a value of 1 if the random number exceeds a threshold
                if (rng_seed > threshold_value) begin
                    rand_normal <= 1;
                end
                else begin
                    rand_normal <= 0;
                end
            end
        end
    endtask


   



always @(posedge clk) begin

        feat_value[ 0] <=1000'b1101001011;
        feat_value[ 1] <=1000'b1010010101;
        feat_value[ 2] <=1000'b1101001010;
        feat_value[ 3] <=1000'b1101001010;
        feat_value[ 4] <=1000'b1101001010;
        feat_value[ 5] <=1000'b1101001011;
        feat_value[ 6] <=1000'b1010010101;
        feat_value[ 7] <=1000'b1101001010;
        feat_value[ 8] <=1000'b1101001010;
        feat_value[ 9] <=1000'b1101001010;
        feat_value[ 10] <=1000'b1101001011;
        feat_value[ 11] <=1000'b1010010101;
        feat_value[ 12] <=1000'b1101001010;
        feat_value[ 13] <=1000'b1101001010;
        feat_value[ 14] <=1000'b1101001010;
        feat_value[ 15] <=1000'b1101001011;
        feat_value[ 16] <=1000'b1010010101;
        feat_value[ 17] <=1000'b1101001010;
        feat_value[ 18] <=1000'b1101001010;
        feat_value[ 19] <=1000'b1101001010;                   
        
        
end
always @(posedge clk) begin

         feat[ 0]<=1000'b1101001010;

         feat[ 1]<=1000'b1101001010;
         //feat[ 2]<=1000'b1101001010;
 
         //feat[ 3]<=1000'b1101001010;
 
        
end
always @(posedge clk) begin

      for (c =0; c<2; c = c+1)begin
           t3 <= 0;
           t2 <=0;
           t1 <= 0;   
           for (f=0; f<2; f = f+1)begin
             
        
              t1 <= feat_value[inputsample[f]];
              t2 <= feat[f] ^ t1;
              t3 <= t3+t2;
           end
           
           textVector <= textVector + t3;
          
            
         
      end
end

assign outvec = textVector;


endmodule

module hamming(
  
    clk,
    
     input_vector
    );
    
parameter  N = 10;
input [N-1 : 0]  input_vector;    
reg [N-1 : 0] vector_class [9 : 0];    

parameter L =10;
reg [9:0] sum_dis;
input clk;
 reg [4:0] minVal;
integer rel_dist;
integer j;
reg [N-1 : 0] distance [9:0];
integer M;
integer d;   
integer min_dist;    


always@(posedge clk) begin

        vector_class[ 0] <=1000'b1101001010;
        vector_class[ 1] <=1000'b1101001010;
        vector_class[ 2] <=1000'b1101001010;
        vector_class[ 3] <=1000'b1101001010;
        vector_class[ 4] <=1000'b1101001010;
        vector_class[ 5] <=1000'b1101001010;
        vector_class[ 6] <=1000'b1101001010;
        vector_class[ 7] <=1000'b1101001010;
        vector_class[ 8] <=1000'b1101001010;
        vector_class[ 9] <=1000'b1101001010;    
end 

always @(posedge clk) begin
      for (M =0;M <N; M=M+1)begin
            rel_dist <= 0; 
            for (d =0; d< 10; d=d+1)begin
                distance[M][d] <= vector_class[d] ^  input_vector;
                if (distance[M][d] == 1'b1) begin
                    rel_dist <= rel_dist + 1;
                end
                sum_dis[d] <= rel_dist;
            end
        end
        min_dist=sum_dis[0];
        minVal = 0;
        for ( j = 1; j < 10; j = j + 1) begin
            if (sum_dis[j] < min_dist) begin
                min_dist = sum_dis[j];
                minVal = j;
            end
        end

       
       
end
   
    
endmodule


Please post your top testbench.

Non-blocking assignments (<=) evaluate the expression immediately but postpone the assignment to the NBA region in the Verilog scheduler. Therefor  t1, t2, t3, etc. are using are using there prior values when an expression is being evaluated. In most cases the initial value is x.
Assuming the function in Asocciate_mem2 accurate, it is recommended to split the logic into its combinational and sequential components
// combinational logic, use auto-sensitivity list (@*) and assign with blocking assignments (=)
always @* begin
  next_textVector = textVector; // init/default value
  for (c =0; c<2; c = c+1)begin
    t3 = 0;
    t2 = 0;
    t1 = 0;   
    for (f=0; f<2; f = f+1)begin
      t1 = feat_value[inputsample[f]];
      t2 = feat[f] ^ t1;
      t3 = t3+t2;
    end
    next_textVector = next_textVector + t3;
  end
end

// sequential logic, use clock edge event and assign with non-blocking assignments (<=)
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) begin // assuming active-high synchronous reset
    textVector <= 0;
  end
  else begin
    textVector <= next_textVector; // synchronize value
  end
end

The hamming module has similar issues. It also lacks a output.
The clk2 in main is an input and being assigned. It is likely created driver conflict resulting in x. Do not assign signals that are inputs of the current scope. Also, clocks typically need to toggle.

Unless you are specifically required to code in Verilog-95 style, it is recommended to change use ANSI style module headers introduced in Verilog-2001. It is more concise making it easier for to read and less prop typos. Example:
module Asocciate_mem2 #(
   parameter  N = 10,
   parameter  L = 10,
   parameter threshold_value = 50
  )(
    output [N-1 : 0]  outvec,
    input  [  3 : 0]  inputsample,
    input             clk,
    input             rst
  );

  reg [N-1 : 0] feat_value [19:0];
  reg [N-1 : 0] ch [19:0];
  reg [N-1 : 0] feat [1:0];
  // ...

